# Defaulthttpclient scheme

Tags: httpclient, jersey

The request is using the wrong scheme (http instead of https). I can see this when i debug my client and inspect the scheme inside the HttpHost object. I'm using JerseyClient to submit the request, it does so by creating a web resource with a URI. I simply pass a string https://myserver.com:443/some/path. However inside the DefaultHttpRoutePlanner class it decides to use the default settings for HttpRoute and uses http. Can anyone tell me how i can override the default settings of the HttpRoute or RoutePlanner classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer -

```
return new HttpHost(request.getURI().getHost(), request.getURI().getPort(), request.getURI().getScheme());
```